# JMeter PerfMon stops monitoring after while

Tags: java, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, perfmon

My perfMon pluggin stops monitoring the server health always after 6 seconds.
[perfMon chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wUs4.png)

I am using:

- jMeter 5.4.1
- ServerAgent-2.2.1
- jre1.8.0_241

I have a successful connection between my client and server station, first metrics are gathered, but always occurs an error:

INFO    2022-09-02 22:00:50.882 [kg.apc.p] (): Binding UDP to 4444

INFO    2022-09-02 22:00:51.882 [kg.apc.p] (): Binding TCP to 4444

INFO    2022-09-02 22:00:51.882 [kg.apc.p] (): JP@GC Agent v2.2.0 started

INFO    2022-09-02 22:01:04.713 [kg.apc.p] (): Accepting new TCP connection

INFO    2022-09-02 22:01:31.092 [kg.apc.p] (): Accepting new TCP connection

INFO    2022-09-02 22:01:31.108 [kg.apc.p] (): Yep, we received the 'test' command

INFO    2022-09-02 22:01:31.889 [kg.apc.p] (): Starting measures: cpu:  memory:

ERROR   2022-09-02 22:02:22.744 [kg.apc.p] (): Error reading from the network layer

java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

```
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonWorker.read(PerfMonWorker.java:181)
    at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonWorker.processCommands(PerfMonWorker.java:97)
    at kg.apc.perfmon.AgentTool.processParams(AgentTool.java:72)
    at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:63)
    at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at kg.apc.cmd.UniversalRunner.main(UniversalRunner.java:175)
```

ERROR   2022-09-02 22:02:23.635 [kg.apc.p] (): Cannot send data to TCP network connection

java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

```
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
    at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonWorker.processSenders(PerfMonWorker.java:281)
    at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonWorker.run(PerfMonWorker.java:243)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I was looking for some clues, but I didn't find them : D.
What do you think is the issue here?

Thanks in advance for your help Guys!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your Server Agent console, if you see something like:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000000bd4ed4, pid=25076, tid=0x0000000000004674
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_261-b12) (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.261-b12 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [sigar-amd64-winnt.dll+0x14ed4]
```

it means that you're suffering from [SIGAR bug 136](https://github.com/hyperic/sigar/issues/136) and it means that you either need to re-compile the `sigar-amd64-winnt.dll` or take the fixed version i.e. from [here](https://github.com/cnstar9988/sigar/raw/master/sigar-amd64-winnt.dll) and replace the one in the "lib" folder of your Server Agent installation.

Also be aware that there is [ServerAgent-2.2.3](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/releases/download/2.2.3/ServerAgent-2.2.3.zip) and [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) and [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so may be it worth considering upgrading

Comment: Hello Dmitri,
Thank you very much for your answer : )
I pasted all data from the console. As you can see there is no issue related to [sigar-amd64].
In that case, the issue is about: "java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" what I saw is the Java issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787447/getting-java-io-ioexception-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the
What do you think about it? How can it be resolved from the side of the jMeter environment? Is that maybe related to some config on the client or server station?

Comment: Hello Dmitri, I have upgraded the jMeter and Server agent as you recommended, but the issue still persists and it's still the same issue as previously.